Derivation of the time derivative of rotating frame of reference
Hello is there a good mathematical derivation of the formula that the time  derivative of the basis vector of the rotating frame with respect to inertial frame of reference is (omega cross position vector) because I saw the derivation in hibbler dynamics book but not satisfied , also i have seen this answer Derivation of the time-derivative in a rotating frame of refrence

See my answer in Notation confusion about time derivative of a vector in a rotating frame. But really, your question is pretty much impossible to answer without you saying what exactly you don’t like, and what exactly you wish to be clarified.

Related : Velocity in a turning reference frame.
